# incorrect if statement value returned

Tags: php

I have an apparently trival if statement that just won't work correctly.

```
if (!empty ($_POST['interest']) && (float)$_POST['interest'] >= 0) {
```

when `$_POST['interest']` is 0 or positive it should return true.
However when it is 0 it is currently returning false incorrectly.

What is going on here?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition will fail when it is 0:

```
!empty ($_POST['interest'])
```

`emtpy()` will be true, so `!empty()` will be false.

All posted values are strings, so to test for a `0` value, you could use for example `$_POST['interest'] === '0'`. However, that would of course fail for a string like `'0.00'`

Comment: You should give the proper way to do it in your answer: use `isset($_POST['interest'])`.

Comment: @Oltarus That's not going to work: It can be set and empty or set and be 0, in both cases `isset` will return `true`.